# Handling empty JSON array specially with jq

Tags: jq, exit-code, empty-list

I'd like the first command exit with status 0 without printing anything. The output and status of the 2nd command should be as shown. Could anybody show me how to modify `jq_expr` to achieve this? (The option `-e` should be maintained.)

```
$ jq_expr='.value | .[] | [.x] | @tsv'
$ jq -e -r "$jq_expr" <<< '{"value": []}' || echo "$?" # I just want this one to exit with 0 instead of 4.
4
$ jq -e -r "$jq_expr" <<< '{"value": [{"x":42}]}' || echo "$?"
42
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I made an mistake. I have fixed the error.

Comment: `$?` is the exit status. I want to make sure the exit status is always 0. It is not part of the output. I never changed the title. Did you change it? I don't find the original version of the title. Could please change the title back to the original one?

Answer (score 0):

[This is a response to the original question, in which the first invocation of jq was given the quasi-JSON value: `{"value": [{x:1}]}`.]

The expression `{"value": [{x:1}]}` is not valid JSON, and so if it is read as though it were valid JSON, the only way to suppress the error message is to redirect it to `/dev/null`.  (jq's exception-handling mechanism cannot be used to catch such syntax errors.)

There are a variety of tools (including jq itself) for converting such quasi-JSON strings to JSON, so you might want to avail yourself of one of those.  For example, consider:

```
$ jq -nc -f <(echo '{"value": [{x:1}]}')
{"value":[{"x":1}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle the case in which .value is the empty array specially, you could use an `if ... then ... else ... end` statement, a `try ... catch ...` expression, or some equivalent.

Since the requirements are not too clear, I'll just point out that you could drop the -e requirement and go with:

```
jq_expr='.value | if length > 0 then map(.x) else empty end | @tsv'
```

If you really want to use the -e option, you might have to use `halt_error/1` as per one of your recent questions on SO.

Comment: ```$ jq -e -r '.value | if length >0 then .[].x else empty end | @tsv' <<< '{"value": []}' || echo "$?"
4
$ jq -e -r '.value | if length >0 then .[].x else empty end | @tsv' <<< '{"value": [{"x":42}]}' || echo "$?"
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): number (42) cannot be tsv-formatted, only array
5 ``` This does not work. The requirement is that the two commands should print the output as is, except the return status should be both 0. Could you check how to modify `jq_expr` to make it work?

Comment: See update.  The -e requirement just complicates things unnecessarily so I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: `$ jq -e -r '.value | if length > 0 then map(.x) else empty end | @tsv' <<< '{"value": []}' || echo "$?"
4` The exit status is still 4. Which statement causes it to return an error exit status? There is not a way to suppress it when `-e` is enabled?

Comment: As I've already said, if you insist on using the wrong option, you can try using halt_error.