# Join array and dictionary into TSV in jq

Tags: json, jq, export-to-tsv

I have the input JSON data at the bottom.

I'd like to generate a TSV output like the following. `<TAB>` is the TAB character. How can I do it in jq?

```
timestamp<TAB>open<TAB>high<TAB>dividends
1623072600<TAB>4229.33984375<TAB>4232.33984375<TAB>
1623159000<TAB>4233.81005859375<TAB>4236.740234375<TAB>
1623245400<TAB>4232.990234375<TAB>4237.08984375<TAB>0.42
1623331800<TAB>4228.56005859375<TAB>4249.740234375<TAB>
1623418200<TAB>4242.89990234375<TAB>4248.3798828125<TAB>
```

```
{
  "timestamp": [
    1623072600,
    1623159000,
    1623245400,
    1623331800,
    1623418200
  ],
  "indicators": {
    "quote": [
      {
        "open": [
          4229.33984375,
          4233.81005859375,
          4232.990234375,
          4228.56005859375,
          4242.89990234375
        ],
        "high": [
          4232.33984375,
          4236.740234375,
          4237.08984375,
          4249.740234375,
          4248.3798828125
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "events": {
    "dividends": {
      "1623245400": {
        "amount": 0.42,
        "date": 1623245400
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Since I did not downvote this question I cannot say why this happened, but since the Q is actually quite interesting, I’d like to point out that questions which do not include an attempted solution are often downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Using jq with the -r command-line option:

```
(.events.dividends|map_values(.amount)) as $dividends
| ["timestamp", "open", "high", "dividends"],
  ( [.timestamp, (.indicators.quote[0] | .open, .high),
     [$dividends[.timestamp[]|tostring]]]
    | transpose[])
| @tsv
```

Notice how the dividends column is computed using the provided $dividends dictionary:

```
$dividends[.timestamp[]|tostring]
```

Comment: What if in some input, `dividends` does not exist? How to make the jq code be robust against such cases?

Comment: You really should avoid asking a new question after the originsl question has been answered and upvoted. Also, you have essentially asked this new question in one of your previous SO qustions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67949284/handling-empty-json-array-specially-with-jq, which has already been answered.

Comment: That previous one is not relevant. I tried with `.events.dividends?`. But it ends up with one column less. I want the last column be all empty, instead of missing entirely.

Comment: The answer is relevant. If you can’t figure it out, maybe you should accept this answer, and ask a new SO question.